# Dictionary List iteration again

Tags: c#, list, loops, dictionary, foreach

I have this loop that I want to iterate through the values of a dictionary, where the values are in the form of a list to find a certain value

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> A = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

  foreach (var item in A[*key*].Values)
            {
                if (A[*key*].Values == *specified value*)
                {
                     a = true; //a is bool variable a made
                }
            }
```

this isnt working, and I am unsure of how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dictionary key to get list of `int`, on this list of int you can use [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx)

```
foreach (var item in A.Keys)
{
    if (A[item].Contains(*specified value*))
    {
         a = true; //a is bool variable a made
    }
}
```

If you do not need to know under what key you found the desired value then you can directly use [Dictionary.Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx) instead of using keys.

```
foreach (var list in A.Values)
{
    if (list.Contains(*specified value*))
    {
         a = true; //a is bool variable a made
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I would skip the `A.Keys` then `A[item]` lookup entirely and just iterate on `foreach(var list in A.Values) { if (list.Contains(*value*))...`

Comment: Yes, that is even better if key is not required under which value is found, updated my answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a LINQ solution:

```
bool a = A.Values
    .SelectMany(list => list)
    .Any(item => item == specifiedValue);
```

Or using standard `foreach` loops:

```
bool a = false;
foreach(var list in A.Values)
{
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        if (item == specifiedValue)
        {
            a = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (a)
        break;
}
```

I'm assuming you would want to break out of the loop once you've found your item. Naturally at this point it's a bit painful to break out of a nested loop, but there are simple ways around this (for example, moving the iteration to a method that returns, or using the dreaded goto) But you may as well use the LINQ solution since (IIRC) it *essentially* boils down to the same nested `foreach` structure anyway.

Comment: Up vote for Linq answer and optimisation of breaking once a == true.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in A[key].Values)
{
    if (item == *specified value*)
    {
         a = true; //a is bool variable a made
    }
}
```